# clock drift at embadded xp

Tags: windows-xp, embedded, system-clock, drift

I am using Windows XP Embedded on my machine, which is installed from a backup image.
Recently, I have detected a system clock drift on my machine. This drift is very large (one second at every 5 minutes).
This drift is not permanent, it randomly happened at every bootup.
But if the unit boots up with a drift, it will stay until the next bootup.
Another important thing is that at the bootup the unit starts with 0 delay every time, for example:

1. booting up the unit.
2. world time is 12:00:00.00, unit time is 12:00:00.00.
3. wait for 10 minutes.
4. world time is 12:10:00.00, unit time is 12:09:58.00.
5. turn off the unit
6. booting up the unit.
7. world time is 12:15:00.00, unit time is 12:15:00.00.

The clock cannot be synchronized.

I installed regular XP ( not embedded) and the drift did not appear.
Can someone give me any help on how to find the root cause of the problem and how to solve it at the Embedded XP?

Answer (score 0):

Many systems will synchronize the operating system's clock to the system hardware clock at bootup, and then maintain the system time purely in software thereafter.  It looks like what's happening is that Windows Embedded is doing that, but the software clock is drifting -- whereas Windows XP is regularly synchronizing the software clock to the hardware clock.

Even if you can't use time synchronization to an external time server, there should still be a way to get Windows Embedded to use the hardware clock.